# Properties of Mertens Function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am astounded by how little information about **[Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function)** *M(n)* (partial sums of the Möbius function) is on the Internet. Thus, I would be thankful if someone could clear up some of my confusion.

First, I learned that PNT (prime number theorem) $\iff M(n)/n \rightarrow 0$  as $n\rightarrow \infty$

This makes sense as *M(n)* is the count of square-free integers up to *n* that have an even number of prime factors, minus the count of those that have an odd number, and I would expect these to cancel out in their contribution to the quotient as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

If *|M(n)|* is bounded by *B*, couldn't we conclude $M(n) = O(B)$? If not, then is *M(n)* finite for all *n* but unbounded? I know $M(n)<n<\infty$ for all *n*.

Furthermore, does anyone happen to know the best big O for *M(n)*? Does anyone know any online sources that exposit on *M(n)*?

I am thankful to anyone that can provide some information.

Comment: I think PNT is equivalent to $M(n)=o(n)$. Anyway, where the internet fails, there is always the library. There are many books where you will find answers to your questions.

Comment: We can, at the very least, say M(n)<n for all n just by the very definition of M(n), without referring to PNT at all.

Comment: I am sorry, you are absolutely right. My concept of "little o" was wrong. I corrected it in my question.

Comment: For instance, I can refer two items from the literature showing *formulas* for Mertens and Möbius function:  Manuel Benito, Juan L. Varona, *Recursive formulas related to the summation of the Möbius function* from  The Open Mathematics Journal , Vol. 1 (2008), and this master thesis (in spanish), I am saying **Lema 1.2.3** in page 6 of Delgado del Sol, *Algunas formulaciones equivalentes a la hipótesis de Riemann*, here from [Universidad Autónoma de Madrid](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/fchamizo/posgrado/TFM_delgado.pdf).  If you need more formulas I could do a more deep search.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late answer on this, but the OP asked to the best big $O$ bound available, and it seems to be unanswered.  I thought it might be useful to have here for future reference.

The best unconditional big $O$ bound that I am aware of is originally due to [Walfisz](http://books.google.com/books/about/Weylsche_Exponentialsummen_in_der_neurer.html?id=sq0cnQEACAAJ), but since his book is out of print, it is best to go to [Ivic's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=jT9gjGipNDUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Ivic%20The%20Riemann%20zeta%20function&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1SeOU9iDHJXTsASv8YDgCQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Ivic%20The%20Riemann%20zeta%20function&f=false), Theorem 12.7, for the statement

> There is an absolute constant $C>0$ such that $$M(x) = \sum_{n \leq x}
>  \mu(n) \ll x \exp(-C \log^{3/5}x(\log \log x)^{-1/5}).$$

and proof.

In addition, some explicit bounds can be found [here](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~ramare/TME-EMT/Articles/Art02.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. $n^{1/2} \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$, is there any problem with that?
2. You can conclude that $M(n) = O(1)$ (or $O(B)$ if you want), if your $B$ is the same for all $n$.
3. Getting information about $M(n)$ amounts to knowing zero-free region of $\zeta(s)$ by Perron's formula, so you would want to look up zero-free region results of $\zeta(s)$. Assume Riemann Hypothesis though, Soundararajan [proved](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0723) that $$M(n) << \sqrt{n} exp((\log n)^{1/2} (\log \log n)^{14})$$

Comment: 1) I made an error, but the contradiction still exists. In one case, M(n) approaches infinity (unless our knowledge of M(n) is so bad that our best big O goes to infinity though M(n) goes to zero). In the other case, M(n) approaches 0. 2) M(n) cannot be O(1) (i.e. O(B)) because that would imply M(n) is O(n^{1/2} + epsilon), which means, according to Wikipedia, we have just proven the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: @David, 1. Ah, I read your PNT line wrongly. I believe that PNT is equivalent to $M(n) = o(n)$, rather than going to 0. 
2. It was unclear what your $B$ is (constant? function?). So I assumed it meant a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I did a Google search for "Mertens" and got these:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensFunction.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConjecture.html

These seem like a good start.

Comment: Yeah, I saw them. Ironically, the article on Mertens conjecture gives more information about Mertens function than the article on Mertens function.